# C# Set complete array to value of x

Tags: c#

I want to set all ints in this array to 1. How can I do this?

public static int[] charlevel = new int[387];

Comment: Take a look at the `for` statement.

Comment: Is there no other way?

Comment: @UngerGames Why do you need another way?  If you already knew how to do it, why are you asking the question?

Comment: Just use `for` loop. Any other answer like using Enumerator is slow.

Comment: @Servy Is that a problem if I want to learn new and maybe better solutions?

Comment: If you want a code review of your existing solution, there's a site for that, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.  Just asking people to tell you something you already knew, as if you didn't already know it, is just wasting everyone's time.

Comment: @Servy if its wasted time dont write comments here...

Comment: @UngerGames I was hoping you'd learn from your mistake and be more considerate of other people in the future.

Comment: Sorry but for me thats not a mistake :) I think I can post any question here.

Comment: This question really has nothing to do with Unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply iterate through an array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < charlevel.Length;i++ ) charlevel [i] = 1;
```

You can also use `Enumerable`.

```
var items = Enumerable.Range(1, 387).ToArray(); // slower than the loop
```

Comment: Basically all you did was combine Anthony's and Zayed answer. Nothing new.

Answer (score 2):

There may be an easier way, but off the top of my head, you could loop through the entire array and set it.

```
for(int i = 0; i < charlevel.length; i++)
{
    charlevel[i] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] charlevel = Enumerable.Repeat(1, 387).ToArray();
```

You need to include this for using Enumerable:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: I knew there had to be an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

If you do that very often you can create an extension method like

```
public static class ExtMethods{
    public static void SetValue<T>(this T[] arr, T value) {
        if (arr != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
                 arr[i] = value;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Then wherever you need to set a value to all indexes of the array you only have to do

```
charlevel.SetValue(1);
```